# Updating denormalised values on postFlush / preFlush?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to figure out the best process for updating de-normalised values in the db.

Here's the scenario:

```
Scenario: Update Activity Duration
    Given the following Task:
    | id | name   | duration
    | 1  | Task 1 | 0
    And the following Activity:
    | id | name       | startedAt        | endedAt | task |
    | 1  | Activity 1 | 2013-01-01 12:00 | null    | 1    |
    When I set "Activity 1" endedAt to "2013-01-01 13:00"
    And persist "Activity 1"
    Then "Activity 1" duration should be 3600
    And "Task 1" duration should be 3600
```

From the data structure you can see that Task.duration is the de-normalised sum of Activity.duration.

What I'm struggling with is when to update the Activity.duration and Task.duration.

Activity.duration could be calculated in the setEndedAt method.

Task.duration is a little more tricky. I'm thinking I'll need to recalculate the Task.duration in the postFlush event when the Activity is modified. I'm assuming it has to be postFlush becuase I want to sum the Activity duration in the DB rather than fetching all the Task.acitivities and looping over them in PHP.

Additionally I want to be able to update multiple Activities at a time (think review / edit timesheet). In this scenario I think I'll need postpone the flush so the unit of work contains all the modified Activities.

The docs actually say:

> postFlush is called at the end of EntityManager#flush(). EntityManager#flush() can NOT be called safely inside its listeners.

which might rule this approach out all together.

Does the proposed solution seem valid? I can't see a way this could be done in preFlush or onFlush as the durations are not saved to the DB yet.

Cheers Leevi

Answer (score 0):

You might get this working with `onFlush` or perhaps `preUpdate`, but I feel like this approach would needlessly couple your domain objects with Doctrine. The best solution would be not to use Doctrine's events at all.

Before changing either the `startedAt` or `endedAt` values of `Activity`, you could subtract the previous duration from the `Task` and then re-add it.

```
class Activity
{
    public function setStartedAt(\DateTime $startedAt)
    {
        $oldDuration = $this->getDuration();

        $this->startedAt = $startedAt;

        $this->updateTaskDuration($oldDuration);
    }

    public function setEndedAt(\DateTime $endedAt)
    {
        $oldDuration = $this->getDuration();

        $this->endedAt = $endedAt;

        $this->updateTaskDuration($oldDuration);
    }

    private function updateTaskDuration($oldDuration)
    {
        $newDuration = $this->getDuration();
        $difference  = $newDuration - $oldDuration;

        $this->task->addDuration($difference);
    }   
}
```

Of course the actual implementation would have to be slightly more sophisticated taking account situations (having no start time, moving an activity from one task to another etc.).

Comment: The only issue I see with this is when setStartedAt and setEndedAt is called before an Activity is assigned to a Task which could happen during form binding (symfony2).

The only time I could be guaranteed that a Task is set is during the persist / update event.

Comment: @LeeviGraham, in theory you could simply update the duration only after the `Task` object is set. As I said, the actual solution would be slightly more complex, but totally doable.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback so far. Should I be concerned that the Activity is modifying the task and telling it what to do directly. It is the "owning side" but lets say that the Task changes and there is no duration anymore. Would it be better to fire an event from the Activity that tells listeners that something has changed: [notify change tracking](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/change-tracking-policies.html#notify). Again this would tie the implementation to Doctrine tho.

Comment: @LeeviGraham, You'd still have to consider all edge cases with the listener approach (what happens if an event is fired, but there's no task & the activity gets added to a task later on) as well plus it feels a tad over-engineered for this use case. Simply extensively test your entities and you should be fine. If you're worried about this changing in the near future, you could create an abstract activity and encapsulate all the duration changing logic in there.